# Batch convert GeoTIFFs to JPEG keeping GPS info

Tags: geotiff-tiff, jpg, exif

How can I convert a batch of GeoTIFFs files to JEPG preserving GPS info on EXIF?

Comment: Quick Bing search gave this: https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Comment: Yes, exiftool is a tool to manipulate exif information of files, does it have a file converter?

Comment: See features: https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#features